# Nodejs installed older version?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, when I was installing nodejs, I used the 
        https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

And when I do node -v I get v0.5.11-pre. Am I correct in assuming this is the wrong node I want to be running for npm? Though I did try installing it using the node-v0.10.4-linux-x64.tar.gz but hit some walls in the setup (as I did it on Webfaction) and couldn't get the make & make install work and had to find a work around.

Is there an easy way to update my nodejs or to redirect it to the correct version?

Comment: What distribution of linux are you using?

Comment: What is the result of `whereis node`?

Comment: I'm using Centos OS 6 64-bit (Webfaction is my host). When I run the whereis node I get node:

Comment: That URL is used for installing `npm`, not for installing `node`. Check out http://serverfault.com/a/299306 on how to install Node on CentOS.

Comment: So, I've followed those instructions... I've got it installed correctly though I don't understand when I do node -v I get v0.5-11pre instead of the version v0.10-5... When I do which node I get ~/bin and that's where my node is.